# ClosedChannelException while uploading file greater than 10mb - wildfly 10.1

Tags: file-upload, wildfly, apache-commons-fileupload

All,

would require your valuable guidance on the below error. I am trying to upload a file with size greater than 10MB.

Server: wildfly 10.1.0 Final
library for file upload 1.3 (apache commons fileupload)

I have tried the following with no success.
a. changed the max-post-size to a large number 300mb 
b. also added to web.xml the

```
 <multipart-config>
              <max-file-size>314572800</max-file-size>   
              <max-request-size>314572800</max-request-size>
        </multipart-config>
```

Stacktrace below

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,586 stderr -        at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSourceConduit.read(ChunkedStreamSourceConduit.java:181)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,587 stderr -        at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,587 stderr -        at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:209)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,588 stderr -        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:2265)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,588 stderr -        at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:294)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,589 stderr -        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:168)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,589 stderr -        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:144)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,590 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:997)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,590 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:901)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,591 stderr -        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,591 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:101)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,592 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,592 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:589)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,593 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:613)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,594 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:630)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,594 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1018)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,595 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:998)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,595 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,596 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,596 stderr -        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,597 stderr -        at com.xx.yy.zz.servlet.auth.FileUploader.doPost(FileUploader.java:181)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,597 stderr -        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
[ERROR] 2017-07-27 08:05:06,598 stderr -        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with Wildfly 10 and apache commons-fileupload 1.3. But in my case setting max-post-size was sufficient. Did you set max-post-size in standalone.xml(or domain) for correct http or https listeners in undertow configuration? Example below:

```
<http-listener max-post-size="304857600" name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
<https-listener  max-post-size="304857600" name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
```

Default values are with 10MB. You can check it in Wildfly/docs/schema/wildfly-undertow_3_1.xsd